# Position and/or scale divs according to scaling background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have a background image that is scaling proportionally according to the height/width of the browser window. I need to place divs on this background, these divs should be positioned relative to the background image. Some of these divs should also scale according to the background image. The most important thing though, these divs should always keep their position in relation to the background image.

A bit stumped with this, is this even possible? Any ideas or hints are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:
Here is a URL illustrating what I'm trying to achieve: http://production.bilbao.fi/bg_test/
The pink box should always maintain the same coordinates (in relation to the background image) no matter how big the background/viewport is.

Comment: Could you post some code for us?

Comment: So the background, as rendered, adjusts in height and width as the viewport (browser window) is adjusted? (I'm assuming you're doing that with JavaScript, no?) So you want the div's to dynamically scale based on the viewport dimesions as well?

Comment: Yep, using JS (the Supersize jquery plugin at the moment) for scaling the background. The divs should then be scaled according to the background/viewport dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I typed up a quick demo that might give you some ideas:

http://jsfiddle.net/techappetite/f74Fg/2/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

#### Example: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/puTxy/)

I'm not sure how you would work it with the Supersize plugin as it crops the image to keep it in proportion, and I wonder what might happen to "hotspots" that get cut out - In my example I'm not using script just have the image scaling to the viewport, which distorts it, but I can't think of a way to get the box to scale without being relative to the viewport percentage

just answering, with an idea and to see if the general idea is to create scalable hotspots?

Comment: Yes, that's just what I'm looking for, but really stumped on the part about keeping the divs/hotspots in proportion too.

Comment: well in mine it's easy as I'm just using (viewport) percentages to size the box as well as position it, so everything is scaling together - however for this to work along side a plugin JS script you'll have to reverse engineer the script to find out how it's proportioning and add some additional script so your Boxes offset and scale accordingly - doesn't sound too easy ;)