# css/html - Opaque layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating my portfolio, I drew some layout but now I've problem with code. As You can see on the image.

Visualisation:

[image]

- the black area will be a photo
- the white area will be a normal bacround color / maybe also image i'll see.
  Full width scalable
  I want to use background image  that will be scalable and the problem is that I've no idea how to resolve problem with the links (grey field). Because I want link gaps to start at the end of the screen and end before the white background (at the boarder).

I was thinking about the image maps but it is not a good solution... Maybe You've got an idea.

I've found similiar problem (about positioning link gaps according to background position - scaleable) - [Link is here - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735479/position-and-or-scale-divs-according-to-scaling-background-image)
Now I have the same problem like in the question above - it is working if I won't use proportional background scaling.

Comment: You can do all kinds of crazy shapes with CSS3. That'll probably be your best bet, as you won't have to mess with Javascript or anything. http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Thx, I forgot about css3 :) But I think I figure it out in another way... Using just a background image in wrapper div with two div's inside with floating - 50% width each. And than try to setup position of the grey fields using CSS3 as You prompted, I think it should work if I will use percentage positionig.

Comment: I have to disagree.  CSS shapes rely on border, and border can not be set to percentage in order to scale widths like he requested.  Pretty sure the only real effective way of doing this would be javascript, especially if he wants it to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tricky layout.. BUT! (I assume full-width scaleable and fixed aspect ratio)

Since you know the angle of the intersection of the areas will be the same. If you put your links at known y-axis percentages from top corner you will have a fixed precentage in the x-axis.

Then if you choose to go full browser width you could use 'position: fixed'(CSS) for the links together with scaling and top/bottom/left/right(CSS).
Otherwise i believe you could use relative positioning with the same principle.

Hope that will get you on your way!